# Is this proof of the "General Power Rule" for derivatives invalid? Here is a possible fix?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I found this proof for the general power rule for derivatives but it feels wrong given that $\ln x$ is defined only for positive $x$ inputs.

Here it is:

[image]

I did however find something that seems to "fix" this issue. We can instead use this

$\frac{d}{dx} x^{2n} = \frac{d}{dx} e^{n\ln x^2} $

Applying the power rule for just positive integers and some basic calculus we get

$\frac{d}{dx} x^{2n} = 2n x^{2n-1} $

The left-hand side now can be thought of as $ \frac{d}{dx} (x^n)^2 $, so we apply the product rule to get $$ 2x^n\frac{d}{dx} x^n = 2n x^{2n-1} $$

solving for $\frac{d}{dx} x^n$ we get the desired result.

If anyone spots any mistakes, let me know please! Also this does not account for the case $x=0$, but this seems trivial since everything is constant there.

Comment: $x^n$ is also defined only for positive $x$. E.g., what is $(-1)^{\pi}$?

Comment: Just complementing. When $n$ is a non-integer, $x^n$ is not define for negative numbers. This is due the defininition of rational exponentiation, $x^{\frac{p}{q}} = \sqrt[q]{x^p}$, where the square root is not always defined for negative numbers. Also, irrational exponentiation is defined as a limit of rational exponentiations, so it ends on the same problem.

Comment: If you really think that "everything is constant at x=0", think again. This seems to indicate a crucial misunderstanding. With this reasoning, all derivatives are everywhere zero. For instance, "everything is constant at x=1" as well.

Comment: Tthanks for the inpts guys. I will look more into it!